# Rails mix up join table name in has many belongs to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, relationship, foreign-key-relationship, rails-activerecord

I'm doing a simple todo app where I only have todo and tag models and a has_many_belongs_to_many relation in between them. I also set up a todo_tags migration for the join which looks like the following:

```
class CreateTodoTagsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def up
  create_table :todo_tags, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :todo_id
    t.integer :tag_id
  end

    add_index :todo_tags, [:todo_id, :tag_id]
  end

  def down
   drop_table :todo_tags
  end
 end
```

But when I try to delete any tag or todo I get the following error eventhough I have not set up any connection between any tags and todos yet.

> Mysql2::Error: Table 'wa2do.tags_todos' doesn't exist: SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `tags_todos` ON `tags`.`id` = `tags_todos`.`tag_id` WHERE `tags_todos`.`todo_id` = 298486374

I don't know where Rails gets the tags_todos table idea, when in the migration my table called todo_tags. Actualy it's an excercise and they requested to use this name.

I have two models they look like this:
Todo
  class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :task_name, :due_date, :finished, :priority

```
 validate :task_name, :presence => true
 validate :due_date_in_future?

 has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

 def due_date_in_future?
  due_date > DateTime.current
 end
```

end

and Tag
    class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :tag_name

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :todos

  validates_uniqueness_of :tag_name, :on => :create, :message => "Tag name must be unique"

end
```

and my controller

```
def destroy
  @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  @todo.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to todos_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something that might be the right answer. And In that case I guess I can only turn it around by using a has many through relationship which I do not need.

> note that the table needs to by named in alphabetical order i.e.
>   categories_stories table as opposed to stories_categories - this is
>   the convention that makes it work.